# Using React Router, how do I redirect to a route when there is a parameter in the URL?

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router-dom

I have a React app using `react-router-dom` and I'd like to create a `<Redirect />` in my top level App component if a condition is met.

```
import { BrowserRouter, Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {

  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  function noUserRedirect() {
    // redirect to Home if user is empty
    if(!user) {
      return (
        <Redirect to="/" />
      );
    }
  }

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      {noUserRedirect()}
      <Route exact path="/">
        <Home />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/dashboard/:id">
        <Dashboard />
      </Route>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I know that `user` is not set. When I visit `/dashboard`, the redirect works and I am brought to the `<Home />` component, but when I visit `/dashboard/123`, for example, the redirect function runs, but I am still brought to the `<Dashboard />` component.

How can I prevent that from happening?

Comment: You might need to move your `noUserRedirect` function below your `Dashboard` route

Comment: I've tested your codes and it seems to be fine FYI.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just redirect programatically, like so:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {

  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  const history = useHistory();

  useEffect(()=>{
    if(!user)
      history.push("/");
  }, [user]);


  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Route exact path="/">
        <Home />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/dashboard/:id">
        <Dashboard />
      </Route>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

It was always working. The reason I didn't think it was working was because I was getting an error in my `<Dashboard />` component.

I was referencing `user` when it didn't exist, but I was confused because **I figured the `<Redirect />` would happen *before* getting to `<Dashboard />`. That's not the case.**

I fixed my error in `<Dashboard />` by putting this at the top of my Dashboard function:

```
// prevent rendering if user does not exist
if(!props.user) {
  return false;
}
```

Once, the Dashboard component returned `false`, the redirect was successful.

I guess the components are rendered before the router makes the redirect. It's not super intuitive but now that I know that, it all makes sense.

Comment: I don't think this is a fix. It's a workaround for an unfixed problem. Why would you have to check if the user is not defined on two places?

Comment: Instead of returning `false` return `<Redirect to="/"/>`. There is a common pattern which solves your problem, it is called PrivateRoute or ProtectedRoute.